# I can't share dynamic variable to my view

Tags: php, algorithm

There is the generated HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $title in <b>/Users/jud3v/Project/my_cinema/App/View/index.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bienvenue dans le projet my_cinema</h1>
</body>
</html>
string(13) "PHP My Cinema"
string(13) "PHP My Cinema"
```

PS: The var_dump that you can see is from View class who i dump my `$this->variables` for the `$title` variable

There is my View class using output buffering function.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Core;

class View
{
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        protected string $_name_of_view;

        /**
         * @var array|mixed
         */
        protected mixed $variables;

    public function __construct($_name_of_view, $variables = [])
        {
                $this->_name_of_view = $_name_of_view;
                $this->variables = $variables;
        }

        public function pathOfViewAndCheckIfExist()
        {
            //Name of the view can be like this movie.index or movie.distributor.index
            //We need to parse it to get the path of the view
            //We need to replace . with /
            //movie.index => movie/index

            $path = str_replace('.', '/', $this->_name_of_view);

            // check if the view exists
            if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/App/View/$path.php")) {
                die("View $path not found");
            }

            return $path;
        }

        public function render(): void
        {
            // start output buffering
            ob_start();
            // extract variable
            extract( $this->variables);
            var_dump($title);
            // include view
            include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/App/View/{$this->pathOfViewAndCheckIfExist()}.php";
            // get content of the buffer and clean it
            $content = ob_get_contents();
            // print content
            echo $content;
        }
}
```

You can see the `var_dump` that work has well :)

But then i show the view i not have the `$title` variable someone can tell me why ?

There is my view index.php:

```php
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bienvenue dans le projet my_cinema</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And for who want to see the controller there it is:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Core\Controller;
use App\Core\View;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public array $request;
    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $title = 'PHP My Cinema';
         (new View('index', ['title' => $title]))->render();
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return 'Identifiant du film que vous souhaiter regarder: ' . $id;
    }
}
```

What i want is to display dynamically the title of the current pages by calling render function from my controller and pass data to the view like a Laravel framework.

PS: This is a school project i can't use any framework only "vanilla PHP" so i have try to build mine.

PS: I know i use `ob_get_contents()` instead of `on_get_clean()` because of testing multiple way to make my things work:

PS: I start my server with this command `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 index.php`

PS: i can share `vendor/autoload.php` if needed.

Comment: I simplified your code and made a quick demo, and it is working as expected: https://gist.github.com/cjhaas/66263f2136f6d370b2a9717e86ac3022

Comment: Thanks you for your time but that not work with your actual change, this is the same.

Comment: Why are you calling `ob_start()` twice? It seems to be reordering the output.

Comment: Because i have try without and this is the same that not make any change